# Flutter - Laravel backend return 419 (Page Expires)

Tags: laravel, flutter, csrf

I have a Flutter app with a Laravel backend. When I make a login call to the login endpoint, I also make a call to Sanctum to retrieve the CSRF token. I save this CSRF token in a global variable and inject it into the header, like this.

```
  String xsrf = "";

  Future getXsrf() async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:80/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 204) {
        String setCookieHeader = response.headers['set-cookie']!;
        xsrf = setCookieHeader.split(';')[0].split('=')[1];
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception('Failed in fetch xsrf');
    }
  }

  Future<UserModel> login(Map<String, dynamic> user) async {
    try {
      await getXsrf();
      Uri url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:80/user/login');
      http.Response response = await http.post(url,
          headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrf},
          body: user);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception('Failed in login');
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the login response is returning a 419 error (Page expired), which is a bit strange because I am correctly retrieving the CSRF token. In Postman endpoint works.

So, has anyone noticed what could be wrong?

Comment: The point of a CSRF is that it changes with each request. AFAIK you can't retrieve a token in a separate request and expect it to be valid. If you need it available to client-side scripts, put it in a hidden form element or a `meta` element in the page's head.

Comment: Typically, CSRF protection is disabled for API routes, which, if you're using Laravel as a backend, would qualify as an API. You'd use a different authentication method, such as Bearer tokens, or similar to verify the request is valid. Edit: It looks like you _are_ using Sanctum, so re-read that documentation to see how to properly use it; CSRF **TOKENS** (not Cookies) with Sanctum seems... odd.

Comment: For API purposes, you should use Laravel Passport which is not using csrf but Bearer Token. I think Sanctum is not build for these.
Create route for API in file named `api.php` (not web.php)

Comment: does it work in Postman ?